# mkdir('../media/magazines/'.$id, 0755) shows a warning: no such file or dir

Tags: php, wamp, mkdir

I don't know whats wrong with this function. I am trying to create a directory `$date/$recid` inside the "media/magazines" directory. This function some times creates it but sometimes shows a warning

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\locallink\cpl_locallink\magazine.php on line 77
Call Stack
```

I am using it on windows 7 with wamp as my server.

Comment: Please stop decorating all questions with "any help please" and other fillers. Such [phrases are redundant](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help4) and unnerving.

Comment: thanks i will take care pf this in future @mario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
mkdir('../media/magazines/'.$id, 0755, True)
```

The main point here is the new argument: the third argument `True`, that said `mkdir` that it must create directories recursively. When recursion switched off all parent directories must be already existent (`../media/` in our case); but when recursion switched on, they will be created automatically.

Comment: it gives me this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\locallink\cpl_locallink\magazine.php on line 77 :(

Comment: try without `recursive =`, only `True`

Comment: ye it worked :) thanks. but what is this "true" for?? is it to force it?? and also edit your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The '[mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)' function doesn't function correctly on Windows when the path
contains forward slashes. The part of the path with the forward slashes
doesn't get created.

```
mkdir('c:/a/b/c/d', 0775, true);
```

You get the error message:
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory

Please use backslashes under Windows or use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

```
mkdir('c:\a\b\c\d', 0775, true);
mkdir('c:'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'a'.
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'b'.
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'c'.
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'d', 0775, true);
```

Comment: But hopefully with `implode()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the directories one by one. $date/$recid is 2.

```
mkdir($date);
mkdir($date."/".$recid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create two directories within the same command, you have to do this in two steps:

```
if (!file_exists($date)) {

    mkdir($date);
}

if (!file_exists($date . '/' . $recid)) {

    mkdir($date . '/' . $recid);
}
```

**EDIT:**

you can use the recursive parameter:

```
mkdir($date . '/' . $recid, 0755, true);
```